# How can I call just one function of a python script from c# without having to open the whole file continuously and just the function?

Tags: python, c#, process, shared-libraries, ironpython

I have a .py script that loads some very heavy files and I would like to open the python program from a C# program and call the different functions without having to continuously open the model.

1. I tried to call it with the IronPython function but I get the following error.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JYtD.png)

If i try to add by the next code:
var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
it appears me the next error_:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q91ZT.png)

2. If I try to do it with a new process I can only call the whole routine, and in each iteration it takes me a long time to open the model and execute it when I only want to call a function once the process has started. How can I do this?  I attach the following code of how I start the process.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHGgO.png)

Comment: Please see [ask]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text